# How to retrieve data?

Tags: php

**Post Model**

```
class Post extends Model
{


    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
    }
```

**Comment Model**

```
class Comment extends Model
    {

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }


   }
```

**Tag Model**

```
class Tag extends Model
    {
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
    }
```

**User Model**

```
class User extends Model
{


    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
```

Now my question is how i can access all comments that belong to post with commented username and tags belongs to that posts.Even i have confusion regarding tag relation because its having many to many relation

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tag Model**

```
class Tag extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
         // Should this be return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post');
    }
```

Now solution for your question is **"EAGER LOADING"**, let's see how we can use it for your situation.

**1. All Comments**

```
$commentsCollection = Comment::all();
// this will give us all comments.
```

**2. Post With Comments and Users and tags**

```
$postsCollection = Post::with('comments','users','tags')->get();
// this will give you collection of post with comments, users and tags. 
//So here you have all tags that belongs the a particular post.
```

**Missing Relation**

You are missing relation between Users and Comments.

**Modified Comment Model**

```
class Comment extends Model
{

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

}

**Modified USER Model**

```
class User extends Model
{


    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }

    public function comments()
    {
         return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
```

Comment: @user1502555.thanks for the answer.how i can retrieve in single query.now i want to retrieve all comments with username that belongs to particular posts with all tag names

Comment: @user1502555.thank you . i am new to laravel .if you know can you post how to retrieve data in single array.so i can easily display data

Comment: sorry instead of just giving answer I am trying to explain as well that's why it's in parts. stay with me and soon full answer will be formed.

Comment: ya no problem .i can wait .take your own time

Comment: B4 I get any further can you please verify in your code that my answer at this point is giving you comments, users & tags for given post?

Comment: i am getting error Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::with()

Comment: hi how to access comment username along with that.i can able to access other info in collection

Comment: That's an issue. From your current relation you missing comment to User relation.

Comment: You need a relation User has many comments and comment belongs to a user. Once you do that relation then only you'll be able to get username of user who made the comment. I will suggest not to look for work arounds because that always come back to bite so do it properly add a user comment relation and you good to go.

Comment: I have added modified user and comment models now from comment object using eager loading you can get user who made that comment.

Comment: Thank you hope you got the solution or somewhere close to it.